# Copy-paste cell values to other sheets

Tags: excel, copy-paste

I am trying to put together some codes that I found here and there to build up a small inventory, sales program. I am stuck at a point where the customer basket is finalized and sold items in the basket should be saved in relevant sheets.

As an example,basket data is in sheet1 (A4:g22), needs to be written to sheet2 and sheet3 with finding the first empty cell in column A. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

```
Private Sub EKSKAYDET_Click()


If Not IsNumeric(Me.eksmiktartxt.Value) Then
MsgBox "Miktari Kontrol Ediniz!"
Me.eksmiktartxt.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNumeric(Me.eksreznobox.Value) Then
MsgBox "ÜRÜN KODUNU Kontrol Ediniz!"
Me.eksreznobox.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If

If eksreznobox.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "ÜRÜN KODU Seçmelisiniz!"
Me.eksreznobox.SetFocus
Exit Sub

End If

If TextBox23 = 0 And TextBox19 = 0 And TextBox20 = 0 And TextBox21 = 0 And TextBox22 = 0 Then
MsgBox "ÖDEME MİKTARI Girmelisiniz!": Exit Sub
Me.TextBox19.SetFocus

End If

If TextBox25.Value = 0 Then
MsgBox "SEPET BOŞ!"
Exit Sub


End If
If TextBox19 = "" And TextBox20 = "" And TextBox21 = "" And TextBox22 = "" And TextBox23 = "" Then
MsgBox "Tutar Girmelisiniz!":
Exit Sub
End If

If eksreznobox.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
ry_bul = eksreznobox.ListIndex + 3

eksadI = Sheets("STOKKARTLARI").Range("D" & ry_bul).Value
EKSSOYADI = Sheets("STOKKARTLARI").Range("E" & ry_bul).Value
textbox12 = Sheets("STOKKARTLARI").Range("h" & ry_bul).Value
TextBox15 = Sheets("STOKKARTLARI").Range("F" & ry_bul).Value
ekstutartxt.Value = eksmiktartxt.Value * textbox12.Value

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("SATISHAREKETLERİ")

lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If Trim(Me.eksreznobox.Value) = "" Then
Me.ekreznobox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Lütfen ÜRÜN KODUNU Girin!"
Exit Sub
End If

With ws
.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.eksreznobox.Value
.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.ekstarihtXT.Value
.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.eksadI.Value
.Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.eksmiktartxt.Value
.Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.ekstutartxt.Value
.Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.textbox12.Value
.Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.EKSSOYADI.Value
.Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox26.Value


Dim llRow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("STOK")

llRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If Trim(Me.eksreznobox.Value) = "" Then
Me.ekreznobox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Lütfen ÜRÜN KODUNU Girin!"
Exit Sub
End If

With ws1
.Cells(llRow, 3).Value = Me.eksreznobox.Value
.Cells(llRow, 1).Value = Me.ekstarihtXT.Value
.Cells(llRow, 4).Value = Me.eksadI.Value
.Cells(llRow, 7).Value = Me.eksmiktartxt.Value
.Cells(llRow, 9).Value = Me.ekstutartxt.Value
.Cells(llRow, 8).Value = Me.textbox12.Value
.Cells(llRow, 5).Value = Me.EKSSOYADI.Value
.Cells(llRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox15.Value
.Cells(llRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox26.Value
.Cells(llRow, 11).Value = Me.TextBox27.Value
ekstutartxt.Value = eksmiktartxt.Value * textbox12.Value
End With


Dim lllRow As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("kasa")

lllRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1) _
.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

If Trim(Me.eksreznobox.Value) = "" Then
Me.ekreznobox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Lütfen ÜRÜN KODUNU Girin!"
Exit Sub
End If
Me.TextBox52.Value = "SATIŞ"

With ws2

.Cells(lllRow, 1).Value = Me.ekstarihtXT.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 5).Value = Me.TextBox19.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 6).Value = Me.TextBox20.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 7).Value = Me.TextBox21.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 9).Value = Me.TextBox23.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 3).Value = Me.TextBox51.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox26.Value
.Cells(lllRow, 4).Value = Me.TextBox52.Value
ekstutartxt.Value = eksmiktartxt.Value * textbox12.Value
End With

With kayit_formu.ListBox6
.BackColor = vbWhite
.ColumnCount = 9
.ColumnWidths = "50;33;45;55;60;55;42;43;60"
.ForeColor = vbBlack
If Sheets("SATISHAREKETLERİ").Range("A1") = Empty Then
.RowSource = Empty
Else
.RowSource = "SATISHAREKETLERİ!a1:i" & [SATISHAREKETLERİ!A1048500].End(3).Row
End If
End With

MsgBox "Bir Kayit Yapildi!"
End With

Me.TextBox25.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEPET").Range("G1").Value)
Me.TextBox24.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEPET").Range("G2").Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thank you Jean for the information. I already tried some of the steps you suggested and looked at many codes but it seems I could not sort it out. I apologize for not uploading the code.

Comment: I now uploaded the code for that command button. Basically I would like to copy whatever in the SEPET sheet  (a4:g22) to other sheets starting from the first empty row in the target.

Comment: So what's wrong with your existing code? For guidance, see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: existing code only copies the values of the textboxes to multiple sheets, which is the last item row in the basket. I need a code to copy and paste the sold items in the basket not the last row only. The basket is sheet "SEPET" . I will in the meantime check the link. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't clarify in a comment — just edit your question.  Also please see this for guidance on properly explaining your problem to maximise your chance of getting help: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
Worksheets(“Sheet1″).Range(“A1:G22″).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets(“Sheet2″).Range(“E5″)
```